# How can I see what an amulet does?

Tags: ziggurat

I prayed to the gods. And got an amulet. I prayed to some other gods. Got a second amulet.

I can activate them be pressing "E", but that doesn't tell me what they do. I tried using one, and it seemed to do nothing at all, except that now that amulet has to recharge. The two amulets look different though, so I expect them to *be* different.

[image: Amulet 1] [image]

I can only carry one, so how can I find out what it does so I know which one to leave behind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clicking 'U' will open up the list of all your perks, inventory, and your character when no level up is present.